# Why do we have to use join method on non daemon processes in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

As per the definition of daemon threads/processes , they do not block the main thread/process from exiting whereas the main thread/process would not exit until its non daemon threads have exited.

If this is the case why do we care about calling the threading.join() method or multiprocessing.join() method on threads/processes.

I am not sure if my assumption about threads and processes is write or not . Kindly point me in the right direction if it is not.

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Not clear on what your question is.  You _don't_ have to use `.join()` at all - if, e.g., you have a non-daemon thread, Python itself will call `.join()` on it all by itself when the interpreter attempts to exit.  Indeed, that's _why_ the main thread blocks:  it's waiting for the `.join()` to complete.

Comment: So if we have 2 or many threads/process running inside a program we don't have to use join at all ? I mean all the examples that i have seen on the web mention that we have to use to block the main thead/process

Comment: Already answered that:  regardless of whether you use `.join()`, Python itself calls `.join()` as part of interpreter shutdown.  Most people do it themselves as part of their own orderly shutdown process.  That's for threads.  It's possible multiprocessing differs in some respect here, although I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`multiprocessing Programming Guidelines`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines).

> Joining zombie processes
>
> On Unix when a process finishes but has not been joined it becomes a zombie. There should never be very many because each time a new process starts (or active_children() is called) all completed processes which have not yet been joined will be joined. Also calling a finished process’s Process.is_alive will join the process. Even so it is probably good practice to explicitly join all the processes that you start.

UNIX operating systems require expired processes to be explicitly "garbage collected". Neglecting so will cause similar issues as when not closing files. You will slowly leak empty process tables until no more will be available and your applications will crash.

Unfortunately, the `multiprocessing` module was designed to reproduce the `threading` APIs and therefore uses the same terminology which sometimes it's confusing. The `multiprocessing.Process.join` in UNIX is similar to the low level C `wait` function.

If you don't want to block waiting for the process to expire, you can regularly poll your expired processes by either setting a timeout of 0 to the `join` or by using the [`multiprocessing.active_children`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.active_children) API. It is usually a common practice to set the `daemon` flag to `True` anyway.